# Database design for Table that refers twice to same table

Tags: database-design

I'm stuck on my database design.

In my database I have "Questions" which can have "Conditions" which are based on a "Question".

Like the following:

- When you add a "Question" in the Table
- I want to add "Conditions" to a "Question"
- Like the Condition: if Question A = 'foobar', show Question B.

In the Application I will do some checks if an Answer given to a Question matches a Condition. If it matches that Condition, it will show the Questions that are added as a Condition.

But what is a good database design for this?
I have the following in mind, but is that a good way? Conditions will be a hasMany relation from Questions table.
[image: example of ERD]

Comment: unclear what's the difference between `question_id` and `condition_question_id`

Comment: Both reffering to the "question" table. So I know when I get a Condition: I can see which question it's conditioned on. This is also the part why I'm asking for help, I can't figure out another way, but I think it can be done easier/better.

Comment: if they both refer to the same table, why do you need both? also in my opinion it is many-to-many relation since the same condition may appear in multiple questions. which means that you remove all foreign keys (like `question_id`) and keep a third table with rows `[ question_id, condition_id ]`

Comment: As an aside, please don't post images where you can just as easily post the actual text as part of your question. Makes it much easier to read.

Comment: @mangusta, that's good thinking. didnt think about that.